# I can not find needed CPU (STM32F401) in IAR 6.5 list

Tags: arm, stm32f4, iar

I'm trying to start STM32 software developing using IAR 6.5 IDE. I have STM32F401C-DISCO board for developing and IAR's IDE.

It is needed to choose the right CPU in the project options menu:

[image]

However there is no such CPU available. After some search for needed packages (search like `IAR STM32F401`...) I have no result.

Do I need to choose nearest CPU (like STMF405)?

Or should I in some way upgrade my IAR IDE?

Comment: I suggest you to use http://www.keil.com/boards2/st/stm32f401c_discovery/

Comment: @ParadoxECE so you're suggesting to use Keil's IDE instead of IAR? Correct?

Comment: Yes, I tried both, and I think that Keil offers a better support for ST microcontrollers.

Comment: @ParadoxECE saying 'support' you're meaning the possibility to pick right CPU in the project configuration list? Or it means more than just 'supported list' like better code generation, less bugs or so?

Comment: I think Keil supports more CPUs and is less buggy than other compilers.

Answer (score 2):

In a newer Version of IAR Embedded Workbench the F401 devices are supported. You might want to try the Kickstarter Version for some preliminary testruns and maybe upgrade to a full version later.

As of now, I'd say IAR was pretty fast to fetch up with the devices with new updates, but lacking in support for newer devices with older versions of their EWARM, but they can be integrated manually I guess - otherwise there wouldn't be benchmarks around on [ULP Bench](http://www.eembc.org/ulpbench/index.php) for the L476 (which is a brand new device) using the v6.6 of IAR EWARM.